# Is steam just a combination of small waterdrops and air?

Tags: thermodynamics, water, gas

I have seen a question here about steam. It made me unsure about the nature of steam. Isn't steam a hot white cloud of water vapor? Is it just water in a gas state, so that its temperature can be higher than 100 degrees? The first thing that springs up in my mind when I think about steam is a hot white "cloud" of vapor. But clouds are no steam. If the water in gas form has a temperature of 100 degrees and the temperature is lowered, the gas turns into liquid and small drops of water are formed. Is this what is called steam? But then how can steam have a temperature of, say, 90 degrees? Water-gas of 90 degrees is no steam. Depending on air temperature, a water gas of 100 degrees will become liquid. Without air, it will stay gas. It will also stay gas if the air is very dry (containing no water yet). For example when you boil water in a vacuum. So, what is steam? Is it the vapor at high temperature or is it the water gas?

Answer (score 2):

Scientifically, steam is water vapor, which is colorless. When liquid water reaches 100 degrees C at standard pressure, it can turn into vapor. Liquid water at standard pressure cannot (normally) be above 100 degrees C, nor can water vapor exist in bulk at less than 100 degrees C under standard pressure. As a body of water boils, water vapor escapes, but it often quickly cools back into liquid water droplets once it leaves the container that's being heated.

Colloquially, "steam" is often used to refer to the cloud of water vapor *and* water droplets. As steam escapes from a kettle, the white cloud you are able to see actually consists of tiny liquid water droplets. It's the same for clouds in the sky - these are just water droplets suspended in the air, which have condensed from the invisible water vapor content of the atmosphere. You'll often hear people refer to a "cloud of steam", although it's technically a cloud of water droplets that are condensing from steam.

Comment: Do you mean with water vapor that the water is gas?

Comment: @Barbierium Yes, water vapor is just another term the gaseous phase of water.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie, you may want to clarify your answer a bit.  Water vapor can and does exist at normal atmospheric temperature and pressure.  That's where humidity comes from.

Comment: It would be less misleading if the statement "When liquid water reaches 100 degrees C at standard pressure, it can turn into vapor." read something like "Although liquid water evaporates at any temperature, upon heating, it tends to boil and evaporate completely at 100°C (at standard pressure)."